# javascript update controls onload

Tags: javascript

iv'e got 2 html pages 
one performs a "get" method on the other 
these pages are duplicates in that they own they both poses a form with the same control types 
and control names

when i submit my form from the source page my url string consist of the values appended together after a '?' char

```
  ....?txtName=era&txtAge=28&gender=male&langHe=on&langEn=on&select=1
```

in the detestation page onload i call a function which splits the control names and their values and sets them

```
        // this is called from <body onload="f();">
        function f() {
        var st = new String(location.search);
        st = st.substring(1, st.length);                        
        var input = st.split('&');

        var value;
        var ctrl;
        var val;
        var _control; 

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) 
        {
            value = input[i].substring(0, input[i].length);
            ctrl = value.substring(0, value.indexOf('='));
            val = value.substring(value.indexOf('=') + 1, value.length);
            _control = document.getElementsByName(ctrl);                
            _control.value = val; 
        }                                                                        
    }
```

i debugged this function and checked that every thing is put in to place as it should 
**the problem** is that after the value are set to the controls
they do not appear on the page , as if they didn't get set at all

additionally in Google chrome i get a "Aw,Snap!" Error after these actions  (Aw Snap happens only when i debug  )

i'm new to java-script and i'm guessing there's a problem with the way i'm assigning these values , i tried also just the first control which is a text type input and it also does not get updated  .

any idea's on why this doesn't work ?
thanks in advance
eran.

Comment: is there a reason you're using javascript to parse and assign things that PHP typically handles?

Comment: yes, it's a school assignment

Comment: this is for Select :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143197/how-to-select-an-option-in-a-select-box-by-the-value-of-the-option-using-javascri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the last line to:

```
_control[0].value = val;
```

UPDATE:

It would be a lot easier if you used [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$('[name='+ctrl+']').val(val);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think jQuery's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function should work for all controls.

Comment: thanks i'm actually going threw them and checking for each case of an input type.

Comment: +1 for mention of a framework. I like ender, which is smaller if you're not using a framework to reduce network overhead.